# Align doesn´t align equations at equal sign

Tags: align, amsmath, mathtools

I´m trying to align multiple equations below each other using align. However the equations are aligned at the right end instead of centered and aligned at the equal sign.

My Latex code looks like this:

```
\begin{align}
\mathbf{i}_{t} = \sigma(\mathbf{W}_{xi}\mathbf{x}_{t} + 
\mathbf{W}_{hi}\mathbf{h}_{t-1} + \mathbf{W}_{ci}\circ\mathbf{c}_{t-1} + 
\mathbf{b}_{i})\\
\mathbf{f}_{t} = \sigma(\mathbf{W}_{xf}\mathbf{x}_{t} + 
\mathbf{W}_{hf}\mathbf{h}_{t-1} + \mathbf{W}_{cf}\circ\mathbf{c}_{t-1} + 
\mathbf{b}_{f})\\
\mathbf{c}_{t} = \mathbf{f}_{t}\circ\mathbf{c}_{t-1} + \mathbf{i}_{t}\circ 
tanh(\mathbf{W}_{xc}\mathbf{x}_{t} + \mathbf{W}_{hc}\mathbf{h}_{t-1} + 
\mathbf{b}_{c})
\end{align}
```

And the output generated looks like this:

[image]

However the equations should be aligned at the equal sign. I´ve already tried multiple approaches but I simply can´t get it to work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments.

Comment: @campa Thank you.  I´ve overlooked the & sign. With it it just works fine

Comment: @MaximilianSpeicher -- It seems that you are not really familiar with the niceties of `amsmath`.  You should consider reading the user's guide -- `texdoc amsldoc` at a command line if you are using a TeX Live installation.

Answer (score 8):

You should give `&` symbol, where you want to align:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathbf{i}_{t} &= \sigma(\mathbf{W}_{xi}\mathbf{x}_{t} + 
\mathbf{W}_{hi}\mathbf{h}_{t-1} + \mathbf{W}_{ci}\circ\mathbf{c}_{t-1} + 
\mathbf{b}_{i})\\
\mathbf{f}_{t} &= \sigma(\mathbf{W}_{xf}\mathbf{x}_{t} + 
\mathbf{W}_{hf}\mathbf{h}_{t-1} + \mathbf{W}_{cf}\circ\mathbf{c}_{t-1} + 
\mathbf{b}_{f})\\
\mathbf{c}_{t} &= \mathbf{f}_{t}\circ\mathbf{c}_{t-1} + \mathbf{i}_{t}\circ 
\tanh(\mathbf{W}_{xc}\mathbf{x}_{t} + \mathbf{W}_{hc}\mathbf{h}_{t-1} + 
\mathbf{b}_{c})
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Raaja done :-)